# Reading a table from database

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-7

I having a problem to run below Java code. I couldn't find the `DB.java` class.

```java
ResultSet rs = DB.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("select * from products");
while(rs.next()){
    System.out.print(rs.getString("pid"));
    System.out.print(rs.getString("name"));
    System.out.print(rs.getString("price"));
    System.out.print(rs.getString("ava_qty"));
}
```

I'm using Glassfish server. Can someone help me to write the `DB.java` class?

Comment: you should be better off with posting an error message

Comment: Can you please add the purpose of the DB.java file. Do you want to achieve connection pooling? or just creating and returning new connection?
Posting answer is something dependent on your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

The getConnection() method is part of the [`DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) class. Initialize your drivermanager properly, as described in this post:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_dbconnection.htm

Example code for future reference:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcConn {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
      } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("Class not found "+ e);
      }
      System.out.println("JDBC Class found");
      int no_of_rows = 0;

      try {
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (
            "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDb","username", "password");  
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM employee");
         while (rs.next()) {
            no_of_rows++;
         }
         System.out.println("There are "+ no_of_rows + " record in the table");
      } catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println("SQL exception occured" + e);
      }
   }
}
```